# new pattern required from an input file using sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have data as below:

```
MGW: VMG110
836-16
836-18
836-19
336-20
836-23
MGW: VMG120
3802-1
3802-2
3802-3
3456-1
3456-4
```

Required output is:

```
VMG110:836-16&-18&&-20&-23
VMG120:3802-1&&-3&3456-1&-4
```

in given data -1,-2,-3,-4 are always in sorted manner

in the output -19 is missing...instead of that -18&&-20 is present..where && means 18 to 20.. please provide the same.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution. The first line of output is different to yours (missing `-` after `&` in the required output?).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $first = 1;
my @line;

sub output {
    print join('&', @line), "\n" unless $first;
}


my $previous = q();
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (s/.*: //) {
        output();
        print "$_:";
        $previous = q();
        @line = ();

    } else {
        my ($prefix, $suffix) = split /-/;
        if ($prefix ne $previous) {
            push @line, "$prefix-$suffix";
        } else {
            push @line, "-$suffix";
        }
        $previous = $prefix;
    }
    undef $first;
}
output(); # Don't forget to output the last line.
```

Comment: yeah...that was typing mistake..corrected now.can u give us in SED or AWK, i have never used perl till now

Comment: Script is working thank yaar...one more modification
VMG110
836-16
836-18
836-19
336-20
836-23
MGW: VMG120
3802-1
3802-2
3802-3
3456-1
3456-4
required output is
VMG110:836-16&-18&&-20&-23
VMG120:3802-1&&-3&3456-1&-4

please provide it.... perl script given by you above is working very fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '-|: ' '
    function printit(  sep,key) {
        sep = ""
        for (key in data) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, data[key]
            sep = "&"
        }
        print ""
        delete data
    }
    $1 == "MGW" {
        if (key1) printit()
        key1 = $2
        printf "%s:", key1
        next
    }
    !data[key1,$1] {
        data[key1,$1] = $0
        next
    }
    {data[key1,$1] = data[key1,$1] "&-" $2}
    END {printit()}
' file
```

```
VMG110:836-19&-23
VMG120:3802-1&-2&-3&3456-1&-2
VMG119:3248-1&-2&3802-8&-9&-10&-11&-12&-13&3457-18&-19&-20
```

Comment: MG110
836-16
836-18
836-19
336-20
836-23
MGW: VMG120
3802-1
3802-2
3802-3
3456-1
3456-4
Required output is:

VMG110:836-16&-18&&-20&-23
VMG120:3802-1&&-3&3456-1&-4
in given data -1,-2,-3,-4 are always in sorted manner

in the output -19 is missing...instead of that -18&&-20 is present..where && means 18 to 20.. please provide the same.